# writing multiple data to json file on connecting leap motion

Tags: python, json

I am using leap motion and saving few parameters in a json file. What I am trying to do is that whenever I place my hand above the leap motion device , the coordinates(values) for those parameters gets saved in the json file. I am able to get only one set of values for each parameters . On putting my hand again the values for the parameters changes instead of saving it as another set of values.How can I change this code to get multiple set of values saved?

```
data = {'F_ID':frame.id , 
       'hand' : len(frame.hands),
       'finger' : len(frame.fingers)
       }


with open('data.json', 'w') as f:

json.dump(data, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your file in append mode :

```
with open('data.json', 'a') as f:
```

Comment: it is still overwriting only. I get this output                                                         {"{hand": 1, "F_ID": 277337, "{finger": 5}. It gets overwritten the next time i place my hand above the device

Comment: @dipitmalhotra change it to `a`!